# Remove rows where vector values don't appear in multiple columns

Tags: r

Vector of list of values in this case ("A","B")

Data frame of every possible combination of A,B,C,D eg

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3...X |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | A | .. |
| A | B | .. |
| A | C | .. |
| A | D | .. |
| B | A | .. |
| B | B | .. |
| B | C | .. |
| B | D | .. |
| C | A | .. |
| C | B | .. |
| C | C | .. |
| C | D | .. |

How do you delete rows where the vector values aren't present in either of the first columns. Taking one column at a time risks deleting rows where the value is present in another column.

Comment: No problem, I formatted it as code for now. This is a useful site if you want to generate markdown tables: https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables

Comment: I don't really understand your question though. Do you want to filter out all rows where `Col1 == "A" and Col2 == "B"`? Or all rows where either `Col1 == "A" or Col1 == "B" or Col2 == "A" or Col2 == "B"`?

Comment: Where col12 == 'A' or col12 == 'B'. So i this example I want to delete rows where Col 1 is C and Col 2 is D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check with `any` if any of the values of your vector appear `%in%` in your rows using `apply` and subset them like this:

```r
values = c("A","B")

df[apply(df, 1, function(x) any(values %in% x)),]
#>    V1 V2
#> 2   A  A
#> 3   A  B
#> 4   A  C
#> 5   A  D
#> 6   B  A
#> 7   B  B
#> 8   B  C
#> 9   B  D
#> 10  C  A
#> 11  C  B
```

If you want to remove if it appears in both columns you can use `all` instead of `any` like this:

```r
df[apply(df, 1, function(x) all(values %in% x)),]
#>   V1 V2
#> 3  A  B
#> 6  B  A
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

**Data used:**

```
df <- read.table(text = "Col1   Col2    
A   A   
A   B   
A   C   
A   D   
B   A   
B   B   
B   C   
B   D   
C   A   
C   B   
C   C   
C   D   
")
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach, not as elegant as @Quinten, but maybe good for your understanding. `%in%` can be used to check if a value is present in a vector, and `|` indicates `or`.

```r
filter_vec <- c("A", "B")

df1[df1$Col1 %in% filter_vec | df1$Col2 %in% filter_vec, ]
#> # A tibble: 10 × 3
#>    Col1  Col2  Col3...X
#>    <chr> <chr> <chr>   
#>  1 A     A     ..      
#>  2 A     B     ..      
#>  3 A     C     ..      
#>  4 A     D     ..      
#>  5 B     A     ..      
#>  6 B     B     ..      
#>  7 B     C     ..      
#>  8 B     D     ..      
#>  9 C     A     ..      
#> 10 C     B     ..
```

Data used

```r
df1 <- readr::read_table(
"Col1   Col2    Col3...X
A   A   ..
A   B   ..
A   C   ..
A   D   ..
B   A   ..
B   B   ..
B   C   ..
B   D   ..
C   A   ..
C   B   ..
C   C   ..
C   D   .."
)
```